# wraps [] around each top-level element of list

Tags: haskell

```
wrap [1,2,3] should output [[1],[2],[3]]
wrap [[1],[2],[3]] should output [ [[1]], [[2]], [[3]] ]
```

my implementation is:

```
wrap [] = []
wrap (x:xs) = [x] :  [wrap xs]
```

and haskell output an error:  Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t ~ [t]

Expected type: [t] -> [t]
Actual type: [t] -> [[t]]

Comment: `wrap (x:xs) = [x] : wrap xs`?

Comment: ^, but also just `wrap = map pure`.

Comment: @zerkms, that causing Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘[a]’ error

Comment: @anru it totally works for me `¯\_(ツ)_/¯ `

Comment: @zerkms, my bad, I had typed wrap :: [a] -> [a]

Comment: Sometimes, it's worth working through an example. You know that for input `[1,2,3]`, you want output `[[1],[2],[3]]`. Now, when you match `(x:xs)`, `x=1` and `xs=[2,3]`. So `wrap xs` should be `[[2],[3]]`. Now think concretely how to get from `[[2],[3]]` to `[[1],[2],[3]]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[wrap xs]` wraps the entire result of `wrap xs`. You don't want to wrap the entire result. You only want to wrap each individual element of the remainder of the list and that is exactly what `wrap xs` already does. Thus, `wrap` is:

```
wrap :: [a] -> [[a]]
wrap [] = []
wrap (x:xs) = [x] : wrap xs
```

The error is telling you that you are trying to use a `[t]` where GHC expects a `t`. This is exactly what we said above, that you are wrapping something too many times.

Comment: thanks, i see what i have done wrong, my type declaration is not there.

Comment: Yes, GHC will happily infer the type of `wrap` for you. Writing top-level type declarations is a good practice, though, and you should get into the habit anyway.

Comment: my bad, I had typed wrap :: [a] -> [a]

Comment: Yes, before you can tell GHC what you want you must first know what you want. :)

Comment: @ReinHenrichs if only it was a haskell extension that could infer an *implementation* from the signature... /me sighs

Comment: @zerkms You should try Agda!

Comment: @zerkms Look up Djinn, on simple (non recursive) cases it often gets it right.